# Why windows are disappearing in my Fedora 23 cinnamon after being minimized?

Tags: fedora, window-manager, desktop-customization, cinnamon

I have a Fedora 23 upgraded from version 21. It all works fine. I also have cinnamon desktop environment. When minimizing any windows in the workspace, it totally disappears instead of going into the low panel of the desktop. I did not have this issue with my old version of Fedora even though I had KDE for the old version.

This also applies to any Terminal that is being minimized; it all disappears. I know it either has to do with some settings or (given the fact that I am new with cinnamon) maybe some extra packages need to be installed. but so far I have been unsuccessful in fixing the issue. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured that out. Here is the processes in the order:

1. Right click on the panel bar down in the bottom of the desktop window.
2. Choose "Troubleshoot" from the dropdown menu.
3. Click on "Rest All Settings to Default".

After the cinnamon starts over, the issue will be resolved.